# Updating a cloned git hub repo

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Extremley beginner question.
So I have forked a git hub repo from someone's profile and then cloned the repo onto my computer's drive. On git bash it says (master). Does making commits and changes to this directory affect the repo on my profile? or on the Master repo I forked this project from?

Not sure what does master refer to.

Thank you,

Comment: Neither. You have an entire local repo; when you commit changes, they’re just committed to it. You can push your changes from your local repo to any of your remote repos, which you can list with the command `git remote -v`. (One will probably be called “origin” and point to your fork on GitHub.) Each branch in your local repo can have an “upstream” remote repo associated with it, which is what you’ll push to if you just run `git push` on that branch without any arguments.

Comment: Ah perfect! Understood, and by commit I meant push (still trying to get used to the terminology here) but you answered that question with the remote -v to see which GitHub profile I am linked to online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always with questions of these sort, I recommend you read the [first 3 chapters of Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), which will explain the Git model and help you understand how it works.

---

To answer your question, first you need to understand what a repository is, and that in itself is pretty straightforward: the codebase and its associated history (this also includes the different versions of the codebase - "branches" - that people might be working on).

Git is called a DVCS, i.e. a *distributed* version control system. The "distributed" is key - it means that repositories do not answer to a central authority. It also means that a full copy of the repository exists on every computer that has a copy of it.

In your case, when you *forked* the repo on GitHub, you created your own copy of the repository on GitHub. When you *cloned* it to *your computer*, you created another copy of your own *on your computer*.

Most Git operations will *only affect your local repository* - this includes commits, merges, etc. There are exactly three Git operations (that most people will ever interact with, anyways) which involve interacting with other repositories: `push`, `fetch`, and `pull`.

`push` reaches out to another computer with a copy of the repository, and says "hey, I've got a version of the same repository - I want to copy changes I've made on my repository to *your* copy". This is why people `push` to GitHub to "upload" their code.

To understand `fetch` and `pull`, you first need to understand that Git maintains what are called "remotes" - copies, on *your* computer, of a remote repository, i.e. a repository that someone else hosts, e.g. GitHub. Git does this because your repository and a remote can diverge: say you do work on your repository, and Jane also does work on her own repository, and she pushes to GitHub: at this point, your repo and the GH repo have diverged. The remote, however, will never diverge from the remote repository itself; it will simply be an older version of the remote repo, and to update it, you use `fetch`. Often you'll also want to `merge` changes from a remote into a local branch when you `fetch`, and that's what `pull` does: it combines `fetch` and `merge` because those two operations are so often done in concert with each other.

Comment: excellent explanation, and thanks for the reference to the documentation. Will be very helpful.